# Nodejs Pythonshell can't find script

Tags: python, node.js

My nodejs api need to use python script.I tried a few techniques.

Nodejs

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

router.get('/pyt', (req, res, next)=> {

    console.log("router get");
# also I tryed with inside the routes folder with PythonShell.run('sample.py', 
    PythonShell.run('../pyt/sample.py', {
      args: ['hello']
      }, function (err, results) {   
          console.log("pshell run");
        if(results)
        { 
           console.log(results);
         }
        if(err)
            { 
             console.log(err);
            }
        });
      });
```

Python

```
import sys
import os

print("first")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("in python script")
    a = sys.argv[1]
    aa=open('sample.txt',"w+")
    aa.close()
    if not os.path.exists(a):
            os.makedirs(a)
    print("last")
```

When I call    http://localhost:3000/pyt then it gives this error.
[Python error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKnSW.png)

Thank you

Comment: you have to figure out where the script is running.  try specifying the full path of the ```sample.py```.

Comment: full path looks like a solution but I will deploy it to the cloud(heroku). Is there any diffrent way

Comment: if you're deploying on Heroku, then you need to find the deploy path and where the sample.py file is saved to.  Unfortunately, I've not deployed anything to Heroku.

Comment: your nodejs file is `app.js`? In that case, you may try `./pyt/sample.py`.